# unzipping a file containing pictures in my app

Tags: java, android

I developed an app where I am backing up and restoring app data. The backup data is stored in .zip format in phone directory. While restoring I am unzipping the file till here everything works fine. But, if the backup contain images as data, while restoring they are not opening in app and giving an error. The code written for unzipping file is written as

```
 public void DBimport(String inFileName) {

       opener= new DataBaseOpener(mApp);
       final String outFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(opener.getDatabaseName()).toString();

       try {

           File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
           ZipInputStream zipInputStream= new ZipInputStream(fis);
           ZipEntry zipEntry= zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

           while(zipEntry!=null) {
               String fileName=zipEntry.getName();
               File newFile= new File(outFileName/* + File.separator + fileName*/);

               new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

               // Open the empty db as the output stream
               OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

               // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
               byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
               int length;
               while ((length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                   output.write(buffer, 0, length);
               }
               // Close the streams
               output.flush();
               output.close();
               zipEntry=zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
           }


           zipInputStream.closeEntry();

           fis.close();

           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Restore Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to Restores. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   }

}
```

May I know where I am going wrong ? and how to resolve this issue. any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: `they are not opening in app and giving an error. ` When are you opening them in your app? And which error? Dit you compare original file size and new file size? Please tell.

Comment: What is the value of `outFileName`? Please put it right in your post.

Comment: What is the value of `newFile.getAbsolutePat()` ? Put it also on the rigth place in your post.

Comment: `String fileName=zipEntry.getName();` You are not using `fileName`. So all extracted files land on the same file.

Comment: @greenapps yes, the restored image isn't opening in app giving error and  says there is some problem saving this image. Whereas other data restore properly its only with images I am getting problem.

Comment: Please answer my question about the sizes.

Comment: `the restored image isn't opening in app giving error and says there is some problem saving this image.` ???? If you try to open that image than you would get an error at loading the image. And why would you save it again? What are you doing?

Comment: @greenapps Ok so let me say in detail.

Comment: @greenapps I have two options in my app as Backup and Restore. Backup option will backup all data in .zip format in phone directory which is working perfectly fine. The Restore option will restore the selected file back into app which is also working fine only problem giving with images as the audio and video files are opening in app after restore.

Comment: Please answer my question about the sizes.  Please answer my question about the sizes.  Please answer my question about the sizes.  Please answer my question about the sizes.

Comment: `String fileName=zipEntry.getName();` REPEAT: You are not using `fileName`. Your code cannot work!!!!!!

Comment: @greenapps the size of file after backup is 3.36Kb and when I restore it the file size is 3.20kB

Comment: @greenapps ok i will rewrite the code